# CSS & HTML: My image is not appearing

Tags: html, css

I've just been teaching my self HTML & CSS and I'm running into my first annoying bug.

Here is my code:

http://pastebin.com/Rk6TjqKZ

It's the only image I have on it so far, and it used to appear, but ever since adding a class to the

I also need help positioning my buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the source of the image as

```
imgur.com/xNiamwg
```

but this is a web page - you need the source to be the actual image itself:

```
http://i.imgur.com/xNiamwg.png
```

(note the PNG extension - not all images have an extension, as it isn't strictly necessary, but they usually do.)

Additionally, you have a semicolon after your source attribute - attributes should only be separated by whitespace.

An example of working code:

```
<a href="http://imgur.com/xNiamwg"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/xNiamwg.png" title="Hosted by imgur.com" /></a>
```

Comment: Nevermind I fixed that! Now how do i go about positioning my button?

Comment: Where do you want to position the button?

Comment: Within the left column, aka this: #outer {
 height: 1500px;
 width: 150px;
 background-color: #E8E8E8;
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: 100px;
 margin-top: 80px;
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F0F0F0 , #D0D0D0 , #909090);
 border-style: inset;
 
}

Comment: To begin with, you should probably move the button into the `div` that represents that column: `<div id="outer"><button...></button></div>`. Also, you can't really post code in a comment - comments aren't intended for extended discussion. You're best off posting a new question. Also, don't forget to mark this answer as accepted if it helped answer the original question! :D

Comment: I'll be able to accept your answer in 3 minutes it says :D Oh yay that worked! Will I be able to manually tweak it from there with margins and such?

Comment: Probably. You can do a lot with CSS, but I can't say how complicated it'd be. Depends what you're trying to do.

Comment: Just trying to center it within the columns.

Comment: Because when I put another button in the same <div></div> They over lap each other and I want them to be moved a little bit.

Comment: You can centre inline elements (that is, elements that behave like text - buttons, images, spans...) with `text-align: center;`. That might work. Again, it depends on the situation. Have a shot at it - you said you're learning, so this is definitely a good exercise - and if you can't get it, put up a question! :D

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem to be working :/ I'll wait another 90 minutes for another question haha. Thanks a bunch for the initial help though!